# How to get Linq to generate all arrays of length n*n containing all permutations of 1..n

Tags: c#, permutation

Please note that this is **not** yet another "how to generate all permutations" question, of which there are loads here. I have looked at plenty of those and am no further in my specific question.

Given an integer `n`, I would like to generate a `List<int[]>` of `int[n*n]` where each list contains a unique permutation of the integers from 1 to `n`.

So if `n` were 2, I would want to see 16 arrays, as follows...

```cs
[1,1,1,1],
[1,1,1,2],
[1,1,1,3],
[1,1,1,4],
[1,1,2,1],
[1,1,2,2],
...etc
[4,4,4,1],
[4,4,4,2],
[4,4,4,3],
[4,4,4,4],
```

For this specific case, it could be achieved with the following...

```cs
Enumerable.Range(1, 2)
  .SelectMany(n1 => Enumerable.Range(1, 2)
    .SelectMany(n2 => Enumerable.Range(1, 2)
      .SelectMany(n3 => Enumerable.Range(1, 2)
        .Select(n4 => new[] { n1, n2, n3, n4 }))))
  .ToList()
```

However, apart from being unwieldly, this is hard-coded for the number 2. If I wanted to do the same for 3, I'd need to have 9 `SelectMany` lines and so on. I would like a flexible solution that would work for whatever number were passed in.

All the other questions I've seen just want all permutations of 1 to `n`, ie a collection of `n` arrays, each of length `n`. My situation requires `n*n` arrays, each of length `n*n`.

Anyone able to help? Thanks

Comment: There is any reason you use list and linQ? If you are working with .NET6 you can use arrays

Comment: @LeandroBardelli No, I just tend to default to Linq for pretty much everything, as it's so clean and elegant. I'm willing to accept other approaches.

Comment: I work a lot with simulations and algorithms and I use arrays and dictionaries or tuples, for performance and readability. Also is more easy to pseudocode than linq (at least for me)

Comment: @LeandroBardelli As I said, I'm fine with another approach, so if you can suggest any code that would solve my problem, I'd be really grateful.  Might also be an interesting exercise to convert your code to Linq 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My situation requires `n*n` arrays, each of length `n*n`.

Based on your own description of your situation (and your code snippet for `n = 2`), *this is not correct*.

**Your situation requires `n^(n*n)` arrays**, each of length `n*n`:

| Max value `n` | Array length `n*n` | Array count `n^(n*n)` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 16 |
| 3 | 9 | 19683 |
| 4 | 16 | 4294967296 |
| 5 | 25 | Oh my |

As we can see, this escalates extremely quickly. Hence,

> I would like a flexible solution that would **work for whatever number were passed in**.

is a rather unrealistic goal, in my opinion.

---

I did find this a fun challenge, though, and I will present my take on it, which works for `n = { 1, 2, 3 }`.
(`n = 4` produces an *Out of memory*.)

**The logic of my implementation is basically:**

1. Calculate the size of each array (`size`)
2. Calculate the size of the resulting list (`permutationCount`)
3. Create a placeholder array, which temporarily holds the values of an array that is to be added to the resulting list (`placeholder`)
4. Populate the resulting list with the very first array
   (for `n = 1`, the first (and only) array is `[1]`)
   (for `n = 2`, the first array is `[1, 1, 1, 1]`)
   (for `n = 3`, the first array is `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`)
5. Populate the resulting list with the remaining arrays

In the very last step, we iterate through each index of `placeholder` and check whether we need to update the value at the given index. We need to update the value at a given index when one of two scenarios occur:

1. it is the last index
2. every *succeeding* value in `placeholder` (which have not yet been updated, seeing as we are iterating `placeholder` and conditionally updating the value from beginning to end) has the maximal possible value. (The maximal possible value is `n`)

The act of *updating a value* will always follow the same rules:

- if the old value is **lower than** the maximal possible value (`n`): **Increase** the value by 1
- if the old value is **equal to** the maximal possible value (`n`): **Reset** the value to 1

As an example: For `max value = n = 3`, the logic would be as follows:

| old value | new value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |

Calculating the new value based on the old value and the max value can be achieved in a straight forward manner by using the modulo operator (`%`):

```
newValue = 1 + (oldValue % maxValue)
```

After the value of all indices of `placeholder` have been evaluated (and conditionally updated), an array with those values are added to the resulting list.

---

**And now, to the actual code:**

I have wrapped the logic inside a method, which can be called with the desired max value.
(`max` is your `n`.)

```
private static List<int[]> GetAllUniquePermutationsOfTheIntegersFrom1To(int max)
{
    const int min = 1;

    int size = max * max;
    int lastIndex = size - 1;
    
    double permutationCount = Math.Pow(max, size);
    
    var placeholder = new int[size];
    Array.Fill(placeholder, min);
    
    var result = new List<int[]> { placeholder.ToArray() };
    
    var isLastEntry =
        (int i) => i == lastIndex;
    var allSucceedingEntriesHaveReachedMaxValue =
        (int i) => placeholder[(i + 1)..].All(entry => entry == max);
    
    while (result.Count < permutationCount)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (isLastEntry(i) || allSucceedingEntriesHaveReachedMaxValue(i))
            {
                placeholder[i] = 1 + (placeholder[i] % max);
            }
        }
        
        result.Add(placeholder.ToArray());
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

Calling the method with `max = 2` and writing the results to the console

```
var uniquePermutations = GetAllUniquePermutationsOfTheIntegersFrom1To(2);

foreach (var entry in uniquePermutations)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", entry));
}
```

produces:

> 1, 1, 1, 1
> 1, 1, 1, 2
> 1, 1, 2, 1
> 1, 1, 2, 2
> 1, 2, 1, 1
> 1, 2, 1, 2
> 1, 2, 2, 1
> 1, 2, 2, 2
> 2, 1, 1, 1
> 2, 1, 1, 2
> 2, 1, 2, 1
> 2, 1, 2, 2
> 2, 2, 1, 1
> 2, 2, 1, 2
> 2, 2, 2, 1
> 2, 2, 2, 2

If nothing else, I hope this can give you some inspiration to build on further, for your own implementation.

Example fiddle is found [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fg2H6g).

Comment: Yeah, I realised late last night that my calculation of the number of perms was way out! Thanks for the code. I'm just playing with it to understand what it does.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean! For 1, 2 and 3 it worked very quickly, for 4 it spent a long time filling up my RAM (I have 64gb, so quite a bit to fill) before I killed it as it was only about 1/10th of the way through! Guess I'll have to give up on that idea. Thanks again.

Comment: Quick calculation: Assuming your PC can generate 1 million perms per second, then for `n=4` it would take about 70 minutes to generate them all. If you used `n=5` (where there are 298023223876953125 perms), it would take about 9450 years! Bit long to wait eh?

Comment: @DreamingOfSleep To be honest, I only tried the code in the fiddle I provided in this answer, so I suppose my own machine would at least not give up quite as quickly :D Whew, nope, that's way too long for me to wait as well, haha.